# How to create a common child state in angularjs project.?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I want to trigger a authenticating modal on expiry of token on client side. I want to make this as a **common child state to all states** so that I can call it from any state.

Is this possible.?

Comment: This is not possible, unless you explicitly define it on each state. But should be common functionality a child? should not that be a named view of a grand-parent/root? *(if it must be handled as a state)*

Comment: The concern is about the state of the app. The background (state) should not change and modal should pop up in whatever state the app is in. Any suggestions ?

Comment: updated comment: I can do this by putting a watcher on token and executing a root controller function that brings up the modal.

But lets say I need to implement login as a state.
The concern is about the state of the app. The background (state) should not change and modal should pop up in whatever state the app is in, when token expires. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can use UI-Router Extras "sticky states"  http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/stickymodal/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create common child state to solve this problem. We can use `resolve` property with our state. `Resolve` gives us one or more promises that must be resolved successfully before the route will change. So you can create a common authentication function and use with `resolve`. For more detail you can refer [link](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/resolve-property-in-angular/) .